# Optimizing Unity Code - InvokeRepeating / StartCoroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a PowerUp with a countdowntimer. For the timer i use InvokeRepeating. But I could also use StartCoroutine.

So which one to choose? I don't really get the difference...

Here my code:

```
float powerUpDuration = 5;               // the duration of the buff
    float slowMotionTimeScale = 0.5f;     // slow down the player by 0.5
    float defaultTimeScale = 1;              // the normal game speed
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)     // player colliding with powerUp
    {
            if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            {
                    Time.timeScale = slowMotionTimeScale;     // time gets slowed
                    Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime * Time.timeScale;     // smooth slow down
                    InvokeRepeating("SpeedManager", 0, 1); // start countdown
            }
    }
    void SpeedManager()
    {
            if (powerUpDuration > 0)         // count to 0
            {
                    powerUpDuration--;
            }
            else              // stop countdown, set timespeed to default
            {
                    CancelInvoke("SpeedManager");
                    Time.timeScale = defaultTimeScale;
                    powerUpDuration = 5;                 // reset timer
            }
    }
```

Comment: You can also just have timer that is in `Update()`, just add `Time.deltaTime` to the timer

Answer (score 2):

`InvokeRepeating()` allows you to invoke something with a set interval.

`StartCoroutine()` Allows you to `fade-wait-unfade` and continue and so on.

Hence it does not really make much difference which one to use over the other. But it might when the functionality you require changes.

Do however consider, if you do not need to do some `fade-wait-unfade` stuff in your function, that it most often is a better fit for one of the many `Update()` functions of unity instead.

`InvokeRepeating()` internaly makes use of reflection, which in 99.99% of the scenarios is slower then using the build in update.

To decide which update would suit the functionality best

`Update`:  Input, Translate/Rotation (non-physics)

`FixedUpdate`: Physics

`LateUpdate`: Camera movement, Animation

Comment: ok, so on a "slow motion" i use fixed update? but is it viable when i just need to use it for 1 time only?

Comment: @Garzec yes. Just dispose of the power up afterwards. Assuming it follows oop

Comment: @Garzec You can also use `Time.timeScale` for "slow motion" effects.

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/478166/view.html):

> InvokeRepeating is easier to learn and use, but, obviously, can only
>   do things at regular intervals. Any weird multi-step, fade-wait-unfade
>   stuff, you have to use a coroutine for (not because of a rule --
>   because there's no way to twist InvokeRepeat to do that stuff.) I'd
>   say, anything you can use InvokeRepeating for, go ahead and do that.
>
> I'd guess that InvokeRepeating is really just running StartCoroutine
>   for you, with a free "every X seconds" delay. So it really makes no
>   difference which you use.